# Adding labels and numbers in axes

Tags: plotting, graphics

Let's see the following test case

```
data = Table[{RandomReal[{-10, 10}], RandomReal[{-10, 10}]}, {i, 1, 50}];
l0 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.01]}];
p0 = Plot[x*Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
s0=Show[{l0, p0}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Axes -> False,
        GridLines -> {{1.5, 7}, {}},
        GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black,Thickness[0.004], Dashed], 
        Method ->  {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-10,10}}, 
        ImageSize -> 550]
```

which produces

[image: plot]

First a minor point: Even though that I define inside `Show` the plot range to be `{{0,10},{-10,10}}`, we see that in the plot both axes exceed the defined limits (i.e., the -0.5 < x < 10.5 instead of [0,10]).

Now my questions:

(a). I would like to add at the position of the vertical lines on the x-axis custom labels like text "P1" and "P2".

OR

(b) Force the program to add the numbers 1.5 and 7 in the horizontal x-axis but without changing the range, I mean to keep the (0,2,4,6,8,10) and add two more inside.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your minor point can be solved using `PlotRangePadding->0`

Comment: Add option `FrameTicks -> {{1.5, 7}~Join~Range[0, 10, 2], Automatic}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Show[{l0, p0},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None},
   {{0, {1.5, Style["P1\n1.5", Red, 14]}, 2, 4,
     6, {7, Style["P2\n7.0", Red, 14]}, 8, 10}, None}},
 Axes -> False,
 GridLines -> {{1.5, 7}, {}},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004], Dashed],
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-10, 10}},
 PlotRangePadding -> 0,
 ImageSize -> 550]
```

[image]

To solve your "minor point" I have added the option `PlotRangePadding -> 0`.

Comment: Do you know about the SE Uploader [palette](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5/can-i-easily-post-images-to-this-site-directly-from-mathematica-yes/32#32)? I ask because I've noticed your graphics don't look very clean.

Comment: Yes it works however by editing manually the ticks all the minor ticks are not shown any more. Why? Can this be fixed?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z The same problem appears in the `Doxumentation`. A certain fix: Replace the last `None` in my `Frameticks`-option with `Automatic`. Now you see the minor ticks at the top of the frame. BTW, thanks for acceptance :)

Comment: @RunnyKine Thank you so much. `SE Uploader` installation went very well and - after watching the video - I could make it work easily. A very clever app :)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps,

```
s0 = Show[{l0, p0}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  Axes -> False, GridLines -> {{1.5, 7}, {}}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004], Dashed], 
  Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-10, 10}}, ImageSize -> 550, 
  FrameTicks -> {{0, {1.5, Style[1.5 , Red, Bold]}, 2, 4, 
     6, {7, Style[7, Red, Bold]}, 8}, Automatic}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Framed["P1"], {1.5, 0}, {-1, 1}], 
    Text[Framed["P2"], {7, 0}, {-1, 1}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same comment as in eldo's answer. All the minor ticks of the x-axis are no longer visible. Why?